# Vba Macro works but not starting in main()

Tags: vba, program-entry-point, solidworks

Have created a Macro - multiple subs, functions and forms for Solidworks.

I'm sure the code is dubious but it works when I force it to start in main()

When I add a button in Solidworks to start the macro it defaults to a different sub, which appears to be alphabetical, I get a similar behaviour starting the macro from the editor.
It appears all the subs listed are the ones with no arguments passed in.

Could anyone please guide me on why this happens? I'm sure I could frig a way around by renaming the subs, but don't realy want to.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It appears I was to impatient, again!

When adding the macro button in Solidworks you are given the choice of choosing the sub to run ... as Method
[image]